# xyplus recursive language

Tags: computer-science, recursion

For `{x, y, +}`, the language `XYPlus` is shown recursively as:

(1)  x and y are in XYPlus .

(2) So if a and b are words in XYPlus , so are ab and a+b.

Which of these would be true or false ?

`xyx+xy`, `y+yx+yy`, `xy++yx+x`, `+xxy+yyx`, `y+xyy+xy+`.

is it saying if it contains xy+ in any of them it will be true, so the only one that is gonna be true is xxy+yyb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of true here.  They are asking if you can construct each string by following the rules above.  $+$ would not be a word in XYPlus because there is no way to generate it from the rules (implicitly, anything not constructible from these rules is not a word in XYPlus).  But x+y+xy is a word in XYPlus:  by rule 1 we have x and y, by rule 2 we have x+y and xy, then applying rule 2 to these we have x+y+xy.

Comment: so plus sign is just like some letter and it wouldn't be treated any differently ?

Comment: In the sense of being a character that is legal in strings and having rules applying to where it appears, yes.  In the sense of not being specified as a legal string in rule 1, it is different from x and y.

Comment: now it makes sense..thank you sir!

Comment: But you could also argue that $x$ and $y$ by rule 1, then $x + y$ by rule 2, then $x + y + x$ by rule 2, and finally $x + y + x y$ by rule 2.

Comment: @vonbrand:  that is correct.  I only need to find one way to derive a word from the rules to prove that it is a word.  Between us we have now proved that this language does not have unique readability.